# Find $x,y \in \mathbb C $ such that $x^5+y^5=275, x+y=5$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, solution-verification

My attempt:

Let $x, y$ be roots of
$$t^2-5t+p=0$$
I got
$$p=\frac{5 \pm \sqrt{-431}}{2}$$
using Vieta's relations.
Now I just calculated x and y using the quadratic formula in $t^2-5t+p=0$.
But I got two very hideous complex values of x and y. So I think my answer may be wrong.

The values I got are
$$x= \frac{5+\sqrt{\frac{253+5\sqrt{-431}}{2}}}{2}, y=\frac{5-\sqrt{\frac{253+5\sqrt{-431}}{2}}}{2}$$ or
$$x= \frac{5+\sqrt{\frac{253-5\sqrt{-431}}{2}}}{2}, y=\frac{5-\sqrt{\frac{253-5\sqrt{-431}}{2}}}{2}$$

Please post your own solutions too if you have any different solutions.

Comment: Observe that pairs $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$ are solutions. It remains to find two others.

Comment: I think you made an error somewhere.  $p=6$ is one possible choice (note $\{x,y\}=\{2,3\}$ is a solution).  The other value of $p$ (which leads to non-real $x,y$) is $p=19$.

Comment: Can you tell me how you got p=6 and p=19?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Substituting $y=5-x$ the equation $x^5+y^5=275$ is equivalent to
$$
(x^2 - 5x + 19)(x - 2)(x - 3)=0
$$

Comment: I was amused by the edits that happened to your answer.  Why did it matter whether $x^2-5x+19$ comes before or after (@user)?

Comment: Nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Observing that the pairs  $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$ are solutions and substituting $y=5-x$ from the second equation into the first one one obtains:
$$
(x^2 - 5x + 19)(x - 2)(x - 3)=0.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3+y^3=(x+y)^3-3xy(x+y)=5^3-3xy(5)$$

$$x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy=5^2-2xy$$

$$(x^3+y^3)(x^2+y^2)=x^5+y^5+x^2y^2(x+y)$$

$$\iff(125-15xy)(25-2xy)=275+5x^2y^2$$

$$\iff(xy)^2-25xy+114=0$$

For the rest, follow [How to solve for $x$ in $\sqrt[4]{x+27}+\sqrt[4]{55-x}=4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616536/how-to-solve-for-x-in-sqrt4x27-sqrt455-x-4/616537#616537)